# jquery shorthand - get multiple selectors match respective divs

Tags: jquery, css, multiple-select, shorthand

Would like the shorthand way for this:

```
// code (works fine) - onmouseover selector1, selector2 (etc), change 'mydiv1', 'mydiv2' (etc) z-index value;
//  onmouseout, restore default z-index value

$('#selector1').hover(function () {
$('#mydiv1').css("z-index", "2")
},
function() {
$('#mydiv1').css("z-index", "");
});

$('#selector2').hover(function () {
$('#mydiv2').css("z-index", "2")
},
function() {
$('#mydiv2').css("z-index", "");
});
```

Out of many tries, this is all i could achieved:

```
$(selector1,selector2).hover(function () {
$(mydiv1,mydiv2).css("z-index", "2")
},
function() {
$(mydiv1,mydiv2).css("z-index", "");
});
```

(only matches the 1st variable) 
I kind of understand why this can't work, but can't make it work anyhow.

How to make selector1, selector2 match mydiv1, mydiv2 (etc) respectively in a shorthand way ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use data attributes. I also would not use hover, I would use mouseenter and mouseleave.

```js
// select the elements with the common class
$(".hover").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function (e) {
  // grab the selector from the hovered element
  var selector = $(this).data("toggles");
  // toggle the display of the element
  // if the element is enter, show it, else hide it.
  $(selector).toggle(e.type === 'mouseenter');
})
```

```css
.x {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hover" data-toggles="#div1">one</div>
<div class="hover" data-toggles=".div2">two</div>

<div id="div1" class="x">Div one</div>
<div class="div2 x">Div two</div>
```

Comment: This would look (more or less) what I need, but it still imply too many changes in my html and compared to my extremely poor knowledge. Moreover I cannot use jqv3 as it breaks other plugin-dependencies (I should have mentionned it earlier), the other version I'm working with just fit my needs. I'm a bit intrigued by you code though, I'm gonna keep it and try to mess around a bit with it (yes, with v3..) just to see if I can get something out of it - Thanks

Comment: You can use whatever version of jQuery, does not matter. There is nothing special in the code. I am not seeing anyway to shorten your code without doing a lot of work. If the naming is sort of the same, you can alter it a bit, but the toggles pattern is used a lot in most libraries.

Comment: Yes, jquery version does matter for me - v3 breaks the older jq plugins which no longer work otherwise (I mean I have others jq script besides this one). I thought it would be only a few lines to change in the original code to be honest, otherwise I'd never asked, my knoweldge of js consists just about changing values, but that's it (well a bit more but not much :) I'll just stick with the original code, ie no shorhand , everything works fine, that's the most important. Thanks for your contribution epascarello.

Comment: I am saying the jQuery version does not matter with my code as long it is not a version that is like 10 years old. It is weird how adding `data-toggles="#div1"` is a huge change.

Comment: epascarello, I guess you couldn't imagine that I work with a version as old as 1.4.2... your code does not work with this version. I absolutly need 1.4.2 just because there isn't any compatibilty issues at all (with the many plugings I'm working with). I just tested your code with 1.7.1 however  and it works - 1.7.1 is compatible with all my plugins, except for one, so I don't use it. Look, for my needs 1.4.2 is fine, I just asked about a shorhand way here as I find a bit stupid to have 10 identical lines in the code with just the #id changing...

Comment: ... I was also interested in about how a shorthand way would work, that's it. Since everything works perfectly fine now (code-wise) and that I have about zero knowledge in js, I just don't wanna change anything else. Hope your undestand. I keep your code, but only for training.

Comment: Congrats on using a 10 year old version of a  library. That means you have to use live() which is bad and why they got rid of it in modern versions. You would have to use attr since it does not have data. You can not just do it with selectors because it is impossible to know what it relates to. Unless your HTML markup gives it as a child or sibling it can be done. And when you post questions about jQuery in the future, make sure you say what version you have to use. We all assume the latest.

Comment: Fair enough.. I was about to reply to the first 2 posts that I should have mentioned about my jq version, when I saw both of them were pointing to version 3 (quite obvious when you think about it), but these posts were removed since then (maybe their authors removed them, I don't know) then I forgot about this omission, and your post came soon after...  I should have mentioned it in the first place that's for sure. It's probably because I'm not too much familiar with this environment, just doing html/css for fun (site is local only). Apologies about that anyway and thank's for your time.